# Reversed Sudoku

Tags: sudoku, reverse-puzzling

Sudoku from [Sudoku Solutions](http://sudoku-solutions.com/).

Here's a Sudoku grid with all the obvious candidates removed. Your task is to re-supply the givens.

[image: find the givens]

Comment: this problem gets harder the more givens given

Comment: JonMark: congratulations on 20k rep!! :D

Comment: Should we put the reverse-puzzling tag?

Comment: @DrXorile; I was going to, but this puzzle doesn't fit the [tag info](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/reverse-puzzling/info), which is to guess the puzzle from some other information

Comment: It's the nature of the puzzle given information about solving it. I would say this would be included in the original intent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think by

> filling in the gaps, we get something like this: [image: unsolved sudoku]

The final solution therefore looks like this:

> [image: solved sudoku]

Answer (score 8):

According to me, the solution would be:

> [image: image description]

Comment: Nice answer!! Think I just got you by a couple minutes! Glad to see we're on the same page :)

Comment: Thanks, @JonMarkPerry! This was a fun puzzle, I haven't done one like this before!

Comment: @El-Guest You're right. By the way it was a fun puzzle, and your answer looks far better than mine. It has my upvote!